# EM wave Polarization

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, polarization

While studying polarization, I read that transverse waves can be polarized and all the EM waves are transverse according to Maxwell's equations. Now, my question is: can all types of EM waves be polarized? And do frequency and energy affect the polarization process?

Comment: Polarization just has to do with how the electric (magnetic) field oscillates in the plane perpendicular to the (any type of) EM wave's direction of propagation; so the type of wave doesn't matter. And by frequency/energy, are you asking about the frequency of the EM wave? If yes, then again, refer to the first point above.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. All EM waves can be polarized, irrespective of their frequency and intensity.

Answer (score 0):

frequency and energy won't change when their planes are changed (polarized)